# challenges in upgrading Bootstrap Themed ASP MVC site, how to upgrade bootstrap + keep previous CSS / @Helper / Transpiler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razorgenerator, razor-declarative-helpers

I've built an ASP MVC site and used bootstrap, Jquery, knockout and signalR, and inherited a  mix of 3rd party MVC code integrated with controls like syncfusion. (I don't have a choice in this matter, company decision)

After coding the HTML helpers in the views,

> I manually applied all the bootstrap styles took sometime and got it
>   to work. **Now, with upgrade/changes to bootstrap (RC 3.1) I am finding
>   myself back to square one, hunting through the code and replacing it manually, lots of
>   changes.** Can you please share a better way to transpile/emit/bind the
>   bootstrap CSS classes into the helpers (*i.e. in an independent way* of the
>   technology helper, whether its ASP HTML MVC helper, Syncfusion HTML
>   MVC helper, Rad or FluentBootStrap)

Please provide a solution/recommendation to apply bootstrap CSS to ASP MVC pages

- That's easy to separate and maintain and CSS upgrade's Programmtically
- or globally configurable/settable/applicable
- I've been thinking extension classes might be a good option, but not sure how I can achieve this, if you've can show me how to get the custom bootstrap CSS bound so I can programatically apply it or globally,
- Is there a transpiler or Razor Declaritve Helper (I know about the nuget package, I tried applying it, and it turned out to be more of a template, than declarative extension binding, and I couldnt use it with other libraries  Syncfusion or DevExpress)
- or some other way, I would greatly appreciate it.

**Here is an example of what I do currently, with the Syncfusion library**

```
@Html.Syncfusion().Menu("myMenu").AutoFormat((Skins)ViewData["Themes"]) - performance hog
```

or better option 2 below

http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/tools/Menu/Appearance

```
@(Html.Syncfusion().Button("btnNormal")
                        .Text("Save")
                        .Width(100)
                        .Height(50)
                        .ContentType(ContentTypes.TextAndImage)
                        .ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Button/icon_save.png"))
                        .CustomCSS("CustomCss_Button") )
```

-> I changed/upgraded manually to BootStrap RC 3.1,  I changed this last part to the bootstrap

```
.CustomCSS("btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-primary"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this would be helpful to you, but check out [TwitterBootstrapMVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc). Right now it supports v2.* of TwitterBootstrap, but the support for v3.* is being built.

Comment: You're definitely one of the best options., (both Telerik and Devexpress was wasted investment, Synfusion customer support is much better, but still doesn't have the answer). Can, you show me how to add your fluent helpers as partial classes or extensions into my source. For e.g. I want add the fluent to emit AFTER our code. @Html.InHouseLabelControl.Bootstrap().LabelFor(x => x.UserName) or  something like that...

Comment: Sorry (timed out), I was looking for e.g. I want add the fluent to emit AFTER our code. `@Html.InHouseLabelControl.Bootstrap().LabelFor(x => x.UserName)` or  something like that...  `@Html.Bootstrap().InHouseLabelControl.LabelFor(x => x.UserName)`

Comment: I don't understand. What is the purpose of InHouseLabelControl? Watch [intro video for TwitterBootstrapMVC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LpWMl5D2i4). This should give you a good idea how you can use it.

Comment: If I use TwitterBootstrapMVC, will that auto update to Bootstrap 3 happen automatically, without changing  my ASP.NET code.  Can you give me an idea on what might change.  **I also see MVC 5 has bootstrap incuded/shipped, I noticed a post in your forum on that, will this supplement or overlap that functionality**

Comment: I answered to the post in the article. Regarding autoupdate to Bootstrap 3 please see [comment to the accepted answer in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904392/challenges-in-upgrading-bootstrap-themed-asp-mvc-site-how-to-upgrade-bootstrap/17926678?noredirect=1#comment26246891_17953642)

Answer (score 1):

Our answer is from the experience we are going through. Here is what we found,

currently, The twitter bootstrap MVC is your best option IMHO, we are moving everything to it and its free! Its probably better the broiler plate option.

1. The 3.0 upgrade is a big question for us as well, so this is
   something Dmitry can clarify.
2. Also, auto creating type safe bootstrap HTML views/sections for models is another question.
3. In addition you will face challenges with custom controls, we have a OLAP BI client, which looks / or doesn't not have the same consistent look. Dmitry can you answer how to resolve this with twitterbootmvc
4. Dmitry, will the twitterbootstrap upgrade, auto upgrade to the 3.0 bootstrap or do we have do anything manually?

Comment: TwitterBootstrapMVC (BMVC) is just a tool that helps you to generate html that is required by Twitter Bootstrap (TB). Right now it supports version 2 of it. However support for version 3 is going to be released soon. Upgrading to the new BMVC will not automatically upgrade TB's css(or less) and js files. That you will have to do by your self. Upgrading to the new BMVC will not restrict you to only TB3. You will still be able to use TB2 by specifying its version in web.config. More information about it will be available when BMVC3 is released.

Comment: This library is **not** free for Bootstrap 3. I'd encourage anyone looking at this answer to carefully look at the licensing before they start building anything with the library.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that in visual studio you can for the precompile of RAZOR into HTML.

Can you add that as an option to fluent